# Behavior of scipy's splrep

Tags: python, scipy, splines

I have a set of data points and would like to approximate them with a spline function.
I used two different functions:

1. *splrep* from scipy
2. and a cubic spline function that I found [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/Cubic_spline_%28Python%29).

The results look like [this](http://postimage.org/image/9wvq9gzdz/).

The code is as follows:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy import *
from scipy import interpolate
#----------------------------------------------
s = arange(257)/256.0
z = s[::-1]
b = transpose(array((z*z*z,
                 3*z*z*s, 
                 3*z*s*s,
                 s*s*s)))
def cubicspline(c,t): 
return dot(b[t],c)
#----------------------------------------------

A = array([
   [ -126.041   ,  246.867004],
   [ -113.745003,   92.083   ],
   [  208.518997, -183.796997],
   [  278.859009, -190.552994]])

a1 = A[:,0]
a2 = A[:,1] 
cs = reshape(A, (-1, 4, 2))
X = []
Y = []
#spline with cubicspline()
for (x,y) in [cubicspline(c,16*t) for c in cs for t in arange(17)]:
X.append(x)
Y.append(y)

# spline with splrep
tck = interpolate.splrep( a1, a2)

xnew = np.arange( min(a1), max(a1), 5)
ynew = interpolate.splev(xnew, tck)
plot(a1, a2, "--ob", ms = 9,  label = "points")
plot(X, Y, "r", lw=2, label = "cubicspline")
plot(xnew, ynew, "g", lw=2, label = "splrep")
legend(); savefig("image.png"); show()
```

As you may see the results of *splrep* are far from being satisfying. 
Can someone please explain this behavior and how to get reasonable approximation from *splrep*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define what you mean by "satisfying". Clearly, your cubic spline is not interpolating through the points, whereas the `splrep` result does (and is perfectly satisfactory in that sense). Note also that your 'cubicspline' is actually just a single polynomial rather than a spline (which are polynomials with breakpoints).

You need to explicitly tell `splrep` that the spline doesn't need to go through the points --- pass in a nonzero `s` smoothing parameter. How to choose this properly, see this question:
[scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline not smoothing regardless of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719754/scipy-interpolate-univariatespline-not-smoothing-regardless-of-parameters?rq=1)

Comment: You're right. Satisfying in the sense that the spline doesn't oscillate "significantly". I' m not sure what the meaning of the smoothing parameter is (I guess I have to do the math). But, it works better this time. http://postimage.org/image/cb8crl2l7/. Thanks for the suggestion.