# Fast b-spline algorithm with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, bspline

I need to compute bspline curves in python. I looked into scipy.interpolate.splprep and a few other scipy modules but couldn't find anything that readily gave me what I needed. So i wrote my own module below. The code works fine, but it is slow (test function runs in 0.03s, which seems like a lot considering i'm only asking for 100 samples with 6 control vertices).

Is there a way to simplify the code below with a few scipy module calls, which presumably would speed it up? And if not, what could i do to my code to improve its performance?

```
import numpy as np

# cv = np.array of 3d control vertices
# n = number of samples (default: 100)
# d = curve degree (default: cubic)
# closed = is the curve closed (periodic) or open? (default: open)
def bspline(cv, n=100, d=3, closed=False):

    # Create a range of u values
    count = len(cv)
    knots = None
    u = None
    if not closed:
        u = np.arange(0,n,dtype='float')/(n-1) * (count-d)
        knots = np.array([0]*d + range(count-d+1) + [count-d]*d,dtype='int')
    else:
        u = ((np.arange(0,n,dtype='float')/(n-1) * count) - (0.5 * (d-1))) % count # keep u=0 relative to 1st cv
        knots = np.arange(0-d,count+d+d-1,dtype='int')


    # Simple Cox - DeBoor recursion
    def coxDeBoor(u, k, d):

        # Test for end conditions
        if (d == 0):
            if (knots[k] <= u and u < knots[k+1]):
                return 1
            return 0

        Den1 = knots[k+d] - knots[k]
        Den2 = knots[k+d+1] - knots[k+1]
        Eq1  = 0;
        Eq2  = 0;

        if Den1 > 0:
            Eq1 = ((u-knots[k]) / Den1) * coxDeBoor(u,k,(d-1))
        if Den2 > 0:
            Eq2 = ((knots[k+d+1]-u) / Den2) * coxDeBoor(u,(k+1),(d-1))

        return Eq1 + Eq2


    # Sample the curve at each u value
    samples = np.zeros((n,3))
    for i in xrange(n):
        if not closed:
            if u[i] == count-d:
                samples[i] = np.array(cv[-1])
            else:
                for k in xrange(count):
                    samples[i] += coxDeBoor(u[i],k,d) * cv[k]

        else:
            for k in xrange(count+d):
                samples[i] += coxDeBoor(u[i],k,d) * cv[k%count]


    return samples




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    def test(closed):
        cv = np.array([[ 50.,  25.,  -0.],
               [ 59.,  12.,  -0.],
               [ 50.,  10.,   0.],
               [ 57.,   2.,   0.],
               [ 40.,   4.,   0.],
               [ 40.,   14.,  -0.]])

        p = bspline(cv,closed=closed)
        x,y,z = p.T
        cv = cv.T
        plt.plot(cv[0],cv[1], 'o-', label='Control Points')
        plt.plot(x,y,'k-',label='Curve')
        plt.minorticks_on()
        plt.legend()
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.ylabel('y')
        plt.xlim(35, 70)
        plt.ylim(0, 30)
        plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
        plt.show()

    test(False)
```

The two images below shows what my code returns with both closed conditions:
[image: Open curve]
[image: Closed curve]

Comment: I wrote an even better implementation of your work
https://gist.github.com/soulslicer/1224bfc6a81f25835054cadf18325251

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So after obsessing a lot about my question, and much research, i finally have my answer. Everything is available in scipy  , and i'm putting my code here so hopefully someone else can find this useful.

The function takes in an array of N-d points, a curve degree, a periodic state (opened or closed) and will return n samples along that curve. There are ways to make sure the curve samples are equidistant but for the time being i'll focus on this question, as it is all about speed.

Worthy of note: I can't seem to be able to go beyond a curve of 20th degree. Granted, that's overkill already, but i figured it's worth mentioning.

Also worthy of note: on my machine the code below can calculate 100,000 samples in 0.017s

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as si


def bspline(cv, n=100, degree=3, periodic=False):
    """ Calculate n samples on a bspline

        cv :      Array ov control vertices
        n  :      Number of samples to return
        degree:   Curve degree
        periodic: True - Curve is closed
                  False - Curve is open
    """

    # If periodic, extend the point array by count+degree+1
    cv = np.asarray(cv)
    count = len(cv)

    if periodic:
        factor, fraction = divmod(count+degree+1, count)
        cv = np.concatenate((cv,) * factor + (cv[:fraction],))
        count = len(cv)
        degree = np.clip(degree,1,degree)

    # If opened, prevent degree from exceeding count-1
    else:
        degree = np.clip(degree,1,count-1)


    # Calculate knot vector
    kv = None
    if periodic:
        kv = np.arange(0-degree,count+degree+degree-1)
    else:
        kv = np.clip(np.arange(count+degree+1)-degree,0,count-degree)

    # Calculate query range
    u = np.linspace(periodic,(count-degree),n)


    # Calculate result
    return np.array(si.splev(u, (kv,cv.T,degree))).T
```

To test it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colors = ('b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k')

cv = np.array([[ 50.,  25.],
   [ 59.,  12.],
   [ 50.,  10.],
   [ 57.,   2.],
   [ 40.,   4.],
   [ 40.,   14.]])

plt.plot(cv[:,0],cv[:,1], 'o-', label='Control Points')

for d in range(1,21):
    p = bspline(cv,n=100,degree=d,periodic=True)
    x,y = p.T
    plt.plot(x,y,'k-',label='Degree %s'%d,color=colors[d%len(colors)])

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlim(35, 70)
plt.ylim(0, 30)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

Results for both opened or periodic curves:

[image: Opened curve]
[image: Periodic (closed) curve]

## ADDENDUM

As of scipy-0.19.0 there is a new [scipy.interpolate.BSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.BSpline) function that can be used.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as si
def scipy_bspline(cv, n=100, degree=3, periodic=False):
    """ Calculate n samples on a bspline

        cv :      Array ov control vertices
        n  :      Number of samples to return
        degree:   Curve degree
        periodic: True - Curve is closed
    """
    cv = np.asarray(cv)
    count = cv.shape[0]

    # Closed curve
    if periodic:
        kv = np.arange(-degree,count+degree+1)
        factor, fraction = divmod(count+degree+1, count)
        cv = np.roll(np.concatenate((cv,) * factor + (cv[:fraction],)),-1,axis=0)
        degree = np.clip(degree,1,degree)

    # Opened curve
    else:
        degree = np.clip(degree,1,count-1)
        kv = np.clip(np.arange(count+degree+1)-degree,0,count-degree)

    # Return samples
    max_param = count - (degree * (1-periodic))
    spl = si.BSpline(kv, cv, degree)
    return spl(np.linspace(0,max_param,n))
```

Testing for equivalency:

```
p1 = bspline(cv,n=10**6,degree=3,periodic=True) # 1 million samples: 0.0882 sec
p2 = scipy_bspline(cv,n=10**6,degree=3,periodic=True) # 1 million samples: 0.0789 sec
print np.allclose(p1,p2) # returns True
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Works flawlessly in my application where I have two end 3d coordinates, and a bunch of known 3d control points. It plots the spline extraordinarily well!  BRAVO!!!  I'm working with ndarrays of 3d image data.

Comment: Great! You prompted me to edit my answer and remove the for-loop at the end which was unnecessary. I also made an addendum at the very end to mention the official BSpline function added in scipy 0.19.0

Comment: Hmmm... I encounter errors with your scipy_bspline function. I pass a list as CV, so cv = np.asarray(cv) was helpful in your original function. Then I use  degree=5 and the new function throws an error and tells me that I need atleast 12 knots ... the old code didn't care, and just worked. So the old code wins for me. :)

Comment: @kabammi ah yes, i forgot to clamp the curve's degree to keep it in check. fixed :)

Comment: by 3D, do you mean 3 degree or 3 dimension?

Comment: @Abhijeet the control vertices `cv` are in 3 dimensions for my use cases. That's what I meant by 3D. But the code works with any dimensions (ex 2D, like my example shows).

Comment: @Fnord Actually I have time series data of a 2D vector and I want to regress/interpolate the entire dataset, can you please help me in how can I use your code for my case. More clearly, I have multiple Y values corresponding to different time, for an x value and there are multiple x values of this kind

Comment: @Abhijeet post your question with some sample data and myself or others will help you

Comment: @Fnord here you are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56421854/python-cubic-spline-regression-for-a-time-series-data

Answer (score 1):

Giving optimization tips without profiling data is a bit like shooting in the dark. However, the function `coxDeBoor` seems to be called very often. This is where I would start optimizing.

Function calls in Python [are expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22893139/3005167). You should try to replace the `coxDeBoor` recursion with iteration to avoid excessive function calls. Some general information how to do this can be found in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159590/3005167). As stack/queue you can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).