# Generating uniformly spaced points along a Spline

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation

Maybe this post is better suited for Code Review SE but here goes:

I have a series of 3-5 points that are fairly distant. I would like to generate a spline using these points and sample N points along the spline. The only tool/algorithm I've found for this is [interparc](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjEjdKpqbiDAxUiAzQIHa85A2sQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fmatlabcentral%2Ffileexchange%2F34874-interparc&usg=AOvVaw3O3JzgQdzdH7sYWek48sVK&opi=89978449) which claims to implement the following logic (expained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118984/5036928):

- Compute the piecewise linear arclength from point to point along the curve. Call it t.
- Generate a pair of cubic splines, x(t), y(t).
- Differentiate x and y as functions of t. Since these are cubic segments, this is easy. The derivative functions will be piecewise quadratic.
- Use an ode solver to move along the curve, integrating the differential arclength function. In MATLAB, ODE45 worked nicely.

So I sought to port the MatLab code to Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline, PchipInterpolator
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def interparc(t, data, method='linear'):
    """interparc: interpolate points along a curve in 2 or more dimensions
    usage: pt = interparc(t,px,py)    % a 2-d curve
    usage: pt = interparc(t,px,py,pz) % a 3-d curve
    usage: pt = interparc(t,px,py,pz,pw,...) % a 4-d or higher dimensional curve
    usage: pt = interparc(t,px,py,method) % a 2-d curve, method is specified
    usage: [pt,dudt,fofthandle] = interparc(t,px,py,...) % also returns derivatives, and a function handle

    Interpolates new points at any fractional point along
    the curve defined by a list of points in 2 or more
    dimensions. The curve may be defined by any sequence
    of non-replicated points.

    arguments: (input)
    t   - vector of numbers, 0 <= t <= 1, that define
            the fractional distance along the curve to
            interpolate the curve at. t = 0 will generate
            the very first point in the point list, and
            t = 1 yields the last point in that list.
            Similarly, t = 0.5 will yield the mid-point
            on the curve in terms of arc length as the
            curve is interpolated by a parametric spline.

            If t is a scalar integer, at least 2, then
            it specifies the number of equally spaced
            points in arclength to be generated along
            the curve.

    px, py, pz, ... - vectors of length n, defining
            points along the curve. n must be at least 2.
            Exact Replicate points should not be present
            in the curve, although there is no constraint
            that the curve has replicate independent
            variables.

    method - (OPTIONAL) string flag - denotes the method
            used to compute the points along the curve.

            method may be any of 'linear', 'spline', or 'pchip',
            or any simple contraction thereof, such as 'lin',
            'sp', or even 'p'.
            
            method == 'linear' --> Uses a linear chordal
                approximation to interpolate the curve.
                This method is the most efficient.

            method == 'pchip' --> Uses a parametric pchip
                approximation for the interpolation
                in arc length.

            method == 'spline' --> Uses a parametric spline
                approximation for the interpolation in
                arc length. Generally for a smooth curve,
                this method may be most accurate.

            method = 'csape' --> if available, this tool will
                allow a periodic spline fit for closed curves.
                ONLY use this method if your points should
                represent a closed curve.
                
                If the last point is NOT the same as the
                first point on the curve, then the curve
                will be forced to be periodic by this option.
                That is, the first point will be replicated
                onto the end.

                If csape is not present in your matlab release,
                then an error will result.

            DEFAULT: 'spline'


    arguments: (output)
    pt - Interpolated points at the specified fractional
            distance (in arc length) along the curve.

    dudt - when a second return argument is required,
        interparc will return the parametric derivatives
        (dx/dt, dy/dt, dz/dt, ...) as an array.

    fofthandle - a function handle, taking numbers in the interval [0,1]
        and evaluating the function at those points.

        Extrapolation will not be permitted by this call.
        Any values of t that lie outside of the interval [0,1]
        will be clipped to the endpoints of the curve.

    Example:
    % Interpolate a set of unequally spaced points around
    % the perimeter of a unit circle, generating equally
    % spaced points around the perimeter.
    theta = sort(rand(15,1))*2*pi;
    theta(end+1) = theta(1);
    px = cos(theta);
    py = sin(theta);

    % interpolate using parametric splines
    pt = interparc(100,px,py,'spline');

    % Plot the result
    plot(px,py,'r*',pt(:,1),pt(:,2),'b-o')
    axis([-1.1 1.1 -1.1 1.1])
    axis equal
    grid on
    xlabel X
    ylabel Y
    title 'Points in blue are uniform in arclength around the circle'


    Example:
    % For the previous set of points, generate exactly 6
    % points around the parametric splines, verifying
    % the uniformity of the arc length interpolant.
    pt = interparc(6,px,py,'spline');

    % Convert back to polar form. See that the radius
    % is indeed 1, quite accurately.
    [TH,R] = cart2pol(pt(:,1),pt(:,2))
    % TH =
    %       0.86005
    %        2.1141
    %       -2.9117
    %        -1.654
    %      -0.39649
    %       0.86005
    % R =
    %             1
    %        0.9997
    %        0.9998
    %       0.99999
    %        1.0001
    %             1

    % Unwrap the polar angles, and difference them.
    diff(unwrap(TH))
    % ans =
    %        1.2541
    %        1.2573
    %        1.2577
    %        1.2575
    %        1.2565

    % Six points around the circle should be separated by
    % 2*pi/5 radians, if they were perfectly uniform. The
    % slight differences are due to the imperfect accuracy
    % of the parametric splines.
    2*pi/5
    % ans =
    %        1.2566


    See also: arclength, spline, pchip, interp1

    Author: John D'Errico
    e-mail: woodchips@rochester.rr.com
    Release: 1.0
    Release date: 3/15/2010"""


    # ===============================================
    #  subfunction for evaluation at any point externally
    # ===============================================
    def foft(t, spl):
        # tool allowing the user to evaluate the interpolant at any given point for any values t in [0,1]
        pdim = len(spl)
        f_t = np.zeros(len(t),pdim)

        # convert t to a column vector, clipping it to [0,1] as we do.
        t = np.clip(t, 0, 1).reshape(-1, 1)

        # just loop over the splines in the cell array of splines
        for i in range(pdim):
            f_t[:, i] = spl[i](t.flatten())

        return f_t
    
    # ===============================================
    #  nested function for the integration kernel
    # ===============================================
    def segkernel(t, y, polyarray):
        val = np.sum(np.polyval(polyarray, t)**2)
        return np.sqrt(val)

    # ===============================================
    #  ode45 solver function to return needed quantities
    # ===============================================
    def ode45(fun, t_span, y0, opts, args):
        sol = solve_ivp(
            fun,
            t_span=t_span,
            y0=y0,
            method='RK45',
            # t_eval=,
            args=(args,),
            vectorized=True,
            events=opts['events'],
            rtol=opts['reltol']
            )
        return sol.t, sol.y, sol.t_events, sol.y_events

    # ===============================================
    # PHASE 1:
    # Assemble information and handle the lienar case

    # t specifies the number of points to be generated equally spaced in arclength
    if isinstance(t, int) and (t > 1) and (t % 1 == 0):
        t = np.linspace(0,1,t)
    elif any(t < 0) or any(t > 1):
        raise ValueError('All elements of t must be 0 <= t <= 1')

    # how many points will be interpolated?
    nt = len(t)
    # the number of points on the curve itself
    n = len(data)
    if len(data) < 2:
        raise ValueError('px and py must be vectors of length at least 2')

    # compose px and py into a single array. this way, if more dimensions are provided, the extension is trivial.
    pxy = data
    ndim = np.ndim(pxy)

    # method may be any of {'linear', 'pchip', 'spline', 'csape'}
    if method not in ['linear', 'pchip', 'spline']:
        raise ValueError("Invalid Method")
    
    # anything that remains in varargin must add
    # an additional dimension on the curve/polygon
    # for i = 1:numel(varargin)
    #     pz = varargin{i};
    #     pz = pz(:);
    #     if numel(pz) ~= n:
        #     error('ARCLENGTH:improperpxorpy', ...
        #         'pz must be of the same size as px and py')
    #     pxy = [pxy,pz]; %#ok
    
    # the final number of dimensions provided
    ndim = pxy.shape[1] # how does this overwrite previous ndim
    # # if csape, then make sure the first point is replicated at the end.
    
    p1   = pxy[ 0,:]
    pend = pxy[-1,:]
    
    # # get a tolerance on whether the first point is replicated.
    # if np.linalg.norm(p1 - pend) > 10*np.spacing(np.linalg.norm(max(abs(pxy),1))):
    #     # the two end points were not identical, so wrap the curve
    #     pxy = np.vstack((pxy, p1))
    
    if not np.allclose(p1, pend):
        pxy = np.vstack((pxy, p1))
        t = np.append(t, 1)
        nt = nt + 1

    # preallocate the result, pt
    pt = np.full((nt,ndim), np.nan)
    # Compute the chordal (linear) arclength of each segment. This will be needed for any of the methods.
    chordlen = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(pxy, axis=0)**2, axis=1))
    # Normalize the arclengths to a unit total
    chordlen = chordlen / np.sum(chordlen)
    # cumulative arclength
    cumarc = np.append(0, np.cumsum(chordlen))

    ###############################################################################################
    # PHASE 2:
    # Handle the linear case if applicable

    # The linear interpolant is trivial. do it as a special case
    if method == 'linear':
        
        # which interval did each point fall in (in terms of t)?
        tbins = np.digitize(t, cumarc)

        # catch any problems at the ends
        tbins[np.bitwise_or(tbins <= 0, t <= 0)] = 1
        tbins[np.bitwise_or(tbins >= n, t >= 1)] = n - 1
        
        # interpolate
        s = (t - cumarc[tbins-1]) / chordlen[tbins-1]
        # be nice, and allow the code to work on older releases that don't have bsxfun
        pt = pxy[tbins,:] + (pxy[tbins+1,:] - pxy[tbins,:]) * np.tile(s, (ndim, 1)).T
        
        # do we need to compute derivatives here?
        dudt = (pxy[tbins+1,:] - pxy[tbins,:]) / np.tile(chordlen[tbins-1], (ndim, 1)).T
        
        # do we need to create the spline as a piecewise linear function?
        # spl = cell(1,ndim)
        # for i in range(ndim):
        #     coefs = [np.diff(pxy(:,i))./diff(cumarc),pxy(1:(end-1),i)]
        #     spl{i} = mkpp(cumarc, coefs)        
        spl = [CubicSpline(cumarc, pxy[:, i]) for i in range(ndim)]

        # create a function handle for evaluation, passing in the splines
        fofthandle = lambda t: foft(t,spl)
        
        # we are done at this point
        return pt, dudt, fofthandle

    ###############################################################################################
    # PHASE 3:
    # Handle the spline or csape or pchip interpolant

    # compute parametric splines
    spl  = [CubicSpline(cumarc, pxy[:, i]) for i in range(ndim)] # list of splines wrt to each dimension of data
    spld = [spline.derivative() for spline in spl]

    # catch the case where there were exactly three points in the curve, and spline was used to generate the
    # interpolant. In this case, spline creates a curve with only one piece, not two.
    if (len(cumarc) == 3) and method == 'spline':
        cumarc = spl[0].x
        n = len(cumarc)
        chordlen = np.sum(chordlen)

    # Generate the total arclength along the curve by integrating each segment and summing the
    # results. The integration scheme does its job using an ode solver.
    seglen = np.zeros(len(cumarc) - 1)
    for i in range(len(spl[0].x) - 1): 
        # polyarray here contains the derivative polynomials for each spline in a given segment
        polyarray = np.zeros((ndim, 3))
        for j in range(ndim):
            # polyarray[j, :] = spld[j].c[i, :] # This is original logic but looks fishy to me
            polyarray[j, :] = spld[j].c[:, i] # This is modified logic

        # integrate the arclength for the i'th segment using ode45 for the integral. I could have
        # done this part with quad too, but then it would not have been perfectly (numerically)
        # consistent with the next operation in this tool.
        t_out, y_out, te, ye = ode45(fun=segkernel, 
                                     t_span=[0, chordlen[i]], 
                                     y0=[0], 
                                     opts={'reltol': 1.e-9, 'events': None}, 
                                     args=polyarray) # careful with this
        # print(y_out)
        seglen[i] = y_out.flatten()[-1] # Not sure why i need to flatten this

    # and normalize the segments to have unit total length
    totalsplinelength = np.sum(seglen)
    cumseglen = np.append(0, np.cumsum(seglen))

    # which interval did each point fall into, in terms of t, but relative to the cumulative
    # arc lengths along the parametric spline?
    tbins = np.digitize(t*totalsplinelength, cumseglen)

    # catch any problems at the ends
    tbins[np.bitwise_or(tbins <= 0, t <= 0)] = 1
    tbins[np.bitwise_or(tbins >= n, t >= 1)] = n - 1

    ############################################################################
    # PHASE 4:
    # Do the fractional integration within each segment for the interpolated points. t is the parameter
    # used to define the splines. It is defined in terms of a linear chordal arclength. This works nicely when
    # a linear piecewise interpolant was used. However, what is asked for is an arclength interpolation
    # in terms of arclength of the spline itself. Call the arclength traveled along the spline s.
    s = totalsplinelength*t

    event = lambda t, y, polyarray: y
    event.terminal = True
    event.direction = 1
    opts = {'reltol': 1.e-9, 'events': event}

    ti = t
    for i in range(nt - 1):
        # si is the piece of arc length that we will look for in this spline segment.
        si = s[i] - cumseglen[tbins[i]]
        # extract polynomials for the derivatives in the interval the point lies in
        for j in range(ndim):
            # polyarray[j,:] = spld[j].c[tbins[i],:] # Again this looks fishy
            polyarray[j, :] = spld[j].c[:, tbins[i]] # This is modified logic
        
        # we need to integrate in t, until the integral crosses the specified value of si. Because we
        # have defined totalsplinelength, the lengths will be normalized at this point to a unit length.
        #
        # Start the ode solver at -si, so we will just look for an event where y crosses zero.
        tout,yout,te,ye = ode45(fun=segkernel, # segkernel takes t, y
                                t_span=[0,chordlen[tbins[i]]],
                                y0=[-si],
                                opts=opts,
                                args=polyarray)
        print(te)
        # we only need that point where a zero crossing occurred if no crossing was found, then we can look at each end.
        if not te or len(te) == 0:
            ti[i] = te[0] + cumarc[tbins[i]] 
        else:
            # a crossing must have happened at the very beginning or the end, and the ode solver
            # missed it, not trapping that event.
            if abs(yout.flatten()[0]) < abs(yout.flatten()[-1]):
                # the event must have been at the start.
                ti[i] = tout[0] + cumarc[tbins[i]] 
            else:
                # the event must have been at the end.
                ti[i] = tout[-1] + cumarc[tbins[i]] 

    # Interpolate the parametric splines at ti to get our interpolated value.
    for L in range(ndim):
        pt[:,L] = spl[L](ti)

    # do we need to compute first derivatives here at each point?
    dudt = np.zeros((nt,ndim))
    for L in range(ndim):
        dudt[:,L] = spld[L](ti)

    # create a function handle for evaluation, passing in the splines
    fofthandle = lambda t: foft(t, spl)

    return pt, dudt, fofthandle


T = np.linspace(0,1,500)**3
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*T)
y = np.sin(np.pi*T)
z = np.cos(3*x + y)
pt, _, _ = interparc(t=100,
                     data=np.column_stack((x, y, z)),
                     method='spline')

fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter3d(x=pt[:,0], y=pt[:,1], z=pt[:,2], name='equispace', mode='markers',
                              marker=dict(size=10, color='red')),
                 go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, name='original', mode='markers',
                              marker=dict(size=10, color='blue'))])

fig.show()
```

Using the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18244715/5036928) the code ran (to my surprise) but did not generate the result I expected:

[image]

Then I realized that the SO answer provided was for a linear interpolant so I decided to compare that also:

[image]

And I suppose the result is better but in this case, there were a lot of points to define the original curve in blue. Since I'm only working with 3-5 points, I'm worried a linear interpolant will not generate the curvature I'm trying to simulate with the spline. Did I incorrectly port some logic from MatLab for the spline case (i.e. does it appear that I correctly implemented the logic steps bulleted above)?

Comment: I don't think you have sufficiently explained the problem. What are the inputs? What is the expected output? Why is the current output wrong?

Comment: Are your points in 2D or a higher dimensional space? If 2D, is your data well described as a function of one of the coordinate (e.g. `y = f(x)`), or does it *need* to be described parametrically (that is, the two coordinates are functions of a third coordinate like `x(t)`/`y(t)`)? If `y = f(x)`, I have a few solutions I can share.

Comment: @MattHaberland Thanks for your comment. I found what I needed (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941799/querying-points-on-a-3d-spline-at-specific-parametric-values-in-python] and haven't had a chance to update this post (though I plan to leave it in case the mostly-ported interparc is of value to someone). But to answer your question, it does need to be described parametrically since the orientation of my splines will change.