# Determining Value of B-Spline at an Arbitrary X Coordinate

Tags: python, data-science, curve-fitting, spline, bspline

I have created an open, clamped, cubic, b-spline on the set of data points xp and yp.

The spline is parametarized by the vector u which spans the domain of xp.

My goal is to determine the "y" coordinate of the b-spline at a given "x" coordinate in the domain of xp.

As is expected behavior when generating parametric curves, when I pass the value "4" into splev after calculating tck, the value for both the x and y coordinate corresponding to the parameter 4 is returned.

I am able to use Newton's method to determine the value of the parameter u at a given "x" coordinate;  This is however indirect and requires more computation time than my final application can permit.

Can anyone suggest a more direct way to determine the "y" coordinate on the b-spline for a given "x"?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

xp = [0., 0.71428571, 1.42857143, 2.14285714, 2.85714286, 3.57142857, 4.28571429, 5.]
yp = [0., -0.86217009, -2.4457478, -2.19354839, -2.32844575, -0.48680352, -0.41055718, -3.]

length = len(xp)
t = np.linspace(0., xp[-1], length - 2, endpoint=True)
t = np.append([0, 0, 0], t)
t = np.append(t, [xp[-1], xp[-1], xp[-1]])

tck = [t, [xp, yp], 3]
u = np.linspace(0, 5., 1000, endpoint=True)
out = interpolate.splev(u, tck)

x_value_in_xp_domain = 4.
y_value_out = interpolate.splev(x_value_in_xp_domain, tck)

plt.plot(xp, yp, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='purple')
plt.plot(out[0], out[1], color = 'teal')
plt.plot(x_value_in_xp_domain, y_value_out[1], marker='o', color = 'orangered')
plt.plot(y_value_out[0], y_value_out[1], marker='o', color = 'black')
plt.axvline(x=x_value_in_xp_domain, color = 'orangered')
plt.show()
```

The below image shows the guide polygon and the b-spline generated by the above code. The orange point at x=4 corresponds the point I wish to directly determine the y value of the b-spline at.  The black point is the value of the b-spline when the value of 4 is passed as a parameter.

[image: Plot from above script]

providing a few useful references:

[Fast b-spline algorithm with numpy/scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803197/fast-b-spline-algorithm-with-numpy-scipy)

https://github.com/kawache/Python-B-spline-examples

https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve.html

http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node17.html

Comment: In general a spline may have multiple Y values for a given X, which will complicate a direct calculation. Could there be a better way of representing your curve?

Comment: @MartinStone Quite true.  Fortuitously in this application, the spline is guaranteed to be single valued for a given X value.

More context on the application, a set of splines will be used to represent solutions which are then passed to an optimizer.  

The endpoints are fixed in this solution space so an open, clamped, cubic, b-spline seemed like a good way to represent arbitrary functions while circumventing Runge's phenomena. 

No opposition to proposals for other methods to approximate arbitrary functions, though still interested in a solution to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The `roots` method of the `PPoly` class may be the solution for your problem. This will be faster than Newton, and it will give you all the solutions in case there is more than one.

```
sx = interpolate.BSpline(t, xp, 3)
sy = interpolate.BSpline(t, yp, 3)

x0 = 4
u0 = interpolate.PPoly.from_spline((sx.t, sx.c - x0, 3)).roots()
sy(u0)

plt.plot(xp, yp, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='purple')
plt.plot(out[0], out[1], color = 'teal')
plt.plot(sx(u0), sy(u0), 'o')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest a frame change. As you know, there are two ways to create a spline in the plane: as a *function* and as a *parametric curve*. You have chosen the latter but nowhere in the question do I see any compelling reason to do so; whereas taking the former would make a solution to your question almost trivial.

We start with some input data.

```py
xdata  = [0.,  0.60626102,  1.36904762,  2.14285714,  2.85714286,  3.63095238,  4.39373898,  5.]
ydata  = [0., -0.82509685, -2.00782014, -2.25806452, -1.99902249, -0.77468231, -1.19975743, -3.]
```

Note that unlike your `xp` and `yp`, which are called *control points* in my circles, I collect a few points `xdata`, `ydata` that we will *interpolate*. I did that by sampling your function at the [Greville abscissae](https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node16.html) to have something similar to your input. However, the exact type of input depends on your application; you have mentioned function approximation in one of the comments, so I guess this might be a way.

Now, we can use [UnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline) to create the spline *function* interpolating the data:

```py
spline = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(xdata, ydata)
```

There are some alternatives; I recommend having a look at the [interpolation tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html#tutorial-interpolate-splxxx) and the references therein.

And this is more or less it. You can now sample the values at a lot of points to plot `spline`:

```py
xfunc  = np.linspace(0, 5., 1000, endpoint=True)
yfunc  = spline(xfunc)
plt.plot(xfunc, yfunc,  color = 'green')
```

However, the reason we go through all this is to answer your question: how to find the *y*-coordinate corresponding to a given *x*-coordinate? This is quite simple:

```py
x_value_in_xp_domain = 4.
y_value_out = spline(x_value_in_xp_domain)
```

Here is a picture showing my input data (blue; again, they are not identical to your inputs), the interpolating spline *function* (green), `x_value_in_xp_domain` (orange curve) and `y_value_out` (orange point).

[image: A plot of the spline function.]

Finally, here is the complete source code.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate

xdata  = [0.,  0.60626102,  1.36904762,  2.14285714,  2.85714286,  3.63095238,  4.39373898,  5.]
ydata  = [0., -0.82509685, -2.00782014, -2.25806452, -1.99902249, -0.77468231, -1.19975743, -3.]

spline = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(xdata, ydata)
xfunc  = np.linspace(0, 5., 1000, endpoint=True)
yfunc  = spline(xfunc)

x_value_in_xp_domain = 4.
y_value_out = spline(x_value_in_xp_domain)

plt.plot(xfunc, yfunc,  color = 'green')
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', color = 'blue')
plt.plot(x_value_in_xp_domain, y_value_out, marker='o', color = 'orangered')
plt.axvline(x=x_value_in_xp_domain, color = 'orangered')
plt.show()
```