# Use B Spline Function on Networkx Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, bspline

I created some Graphs with networkx and now I want to smooth the connections of them with a B-Spline function. I found an very helpful post here for that: [B-Spline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612626/b-spline-interpolation-with-python) But if I want to do it like that the order of the points is very important. For some Graphs it is easy to order them, but if they conclude T-Junctions it gets more difficult. For example it worked for this Graph pretty good and the results of the other graphs should look similar to that:
[Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8jmS.png)
[Example Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89SDi.png)

But I had some issues for this graphs:
[Issue: Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp2wO.png)
[Issue: Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAnse.png)

The function for the working example is:

```
def bSplineCurves(G):
    connectedComp = nx.connected_components(G)
    for comp in connectedComp:
        sortedComp = sortNodes(G, list(comp))
        points = tuplesToPoints(sortedComp)
        degree = 3

        points = points + points[0:degree + 1]
        points = np.array(points)
        x = points[:,0]
        y = points[:,1]

        t = range(len(x))
        ipl_t = np.linspace(1.0, len(points) - degree, 1000)

        x_tup = si.splrep(t, x, k=degree, per=1)
        y_tup = si.splrep(t, y, k=degree, per=1)
        x_list = list(x_tup)
        xl = x.tolist()
        x_list[1] = [0.0] + xl + [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

        y_list = list(y_tup)
        yl = y.tolist()
        y_list[1] = [0.0] + yl + [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

        x_i = si.splev(ipl_t, x_list)
        y_i = si.splev(ipl_t, y_list)

        plt.plot(x_i, y_i, 'r')
    plt.show()
    return G
```

Has anybody an alternative way to use the B-Spline function on graphs? Or does anybody knows a good way to sort every kind of component that is returned by the connected_components function?

Edit:

With the help of the comment from @Paul Broderson I've manged to reach the following results:
[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt0Qj.png)
[Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQfBk.png)

The chain_decomposition function works good on the first result, but not for the second. It didn't recognize the edges at the outside of the graph, that are not part of a cycle. Is there another function that would detect every path? Or do I have to implement something by myself?

My current code:

```
def chainToPoints(chain):
    points = list()
    for edge in chain:
        points.append(edge[0])
    points.append(chain[-1][1])
    return points


def bSplineCurvesAlternative(G):
    chain_decomposition = nx.chain_decomposition(G)
    for chain in chain_decomposition:
        points = chainToPoints(chain, G)
        if points[0] == points[-1]:
            bSplineForCycle(points)
        else:
            bSplineForPath(points)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of iterating over connected components, I would fit a spline to each chain, i.e. connected vertices with degree 2 + endpoints. There is a function `chain_decomposition` in networkx that might fit the bill, but I am not sure if the returned chains include the endpoints. You would have to check. Also, `chain_decomposition` returns a list of edges, so you would have to convert that into a correctly ordered set of nodes first.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Thank you for your answer. This helped a lot. I edit my question, because the function didn't detect some edges that are not part of a cycle (Result 2). Is there another function that would detect all of them?