# scipy UnivariateSpline returning Nan values

Tags: python, scipy

I am having trouble getting UnivariateSpline working and cannot understand why. here is my code

```
x = gg
y = AA
order = np.argsort(x)
s = UnivariateSpline(x[order], y[order],s=2)
xs =np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(),1000)
ys = s(xs)
print ys, xs
plt.plot(x, y, 'kx')
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

I have ordered x so it is increasing but when I print ys it only produced Nan, why is this? I have also included my data.

x=[0.87   0.87   1.03   1.11   1.73   1.35   1.06   0.96   0.95   0.88   1.93
  1.47   0.86   1.11   1.11   0.87   1.6    1.49   1.69   1.69   1.45   1.27
  1.44   1.02   1.55   0.89   1.     1.15   0.95   1.35   1.01   0.94   1.33
  1.06   1.02   1.69   1.3    0.95   1.44   1.26   1.19   1.11   1.15   1.88
  0.99   1.08   1.12   1.05   1.83   1.02   1.47   1.45   1.05   0.94   1.13
  1.13   0.96   1.16   0.96   1.     1.27   1.59   0.93   0.95   0.98   1.28
  1.15   1.07   1.13   1.03   1.11   1.239  1.62   1.47   1.33   1.09   1.07
  1.32   1.66   1.34   1.2    1.33   1.36   0.91   1.16   1.11   1.19   0.81
  0.848  1.08   1.303  1.15   0.978  0.793  1.182  1.144  1.028  1.414
  1.154  0.971  1.582  1.69   0.84   1.68   1.563  1.31   0.96   1.645
  1.562  1.115  1.744  0.91   0.68   0.933  1.346  0.965  1.058  1.23
  0.981  0.811  1.274  1.492  0.905  1.148  0.962  1.864  1.029  1.433
  1.29   0.996  1.087  1.808  1.708  1.296  0.987  1.04   1.39   1.284
  1.203  1.384  1.381  1.494  1.475  0.95   0.979  1.243  1.693  1.056
  0.987  1.637  0.927  1.104  1.727  1.091  0.683  0.888  1.312  1.286
  1.383  1.39   0.963  1.399  1.775  1.708  1.394  1.08   1.22   1.309
  0.882  0.938  0.827  1.239  1.08   0.993  1.414  1.543  1.384  1.397
  1.309  0.813  0.905  1.308  1.097  1.222  1.806  1.373  1.04   1.953
  1.014  1.053  1.744  1.078  0.999  0.958  1.362  1.25   1.105  1.212
  1.08   1.1    1.15   1.04   1.93   1.3    1.06   1.93   1.47   1.66   1.87
  0.79   1.47   1.01   0.99   1.39   1.02   1.26   0.88   1.039  1.56   1.56
  1.28   1.46   1.49   1.15   1.05   1.32   1.69   1.13   1.04   1.22   1.32
  1.13 ]

y=[-20.75773476 -21.95605805 -18.55369454 -20.67245856 -19.62696343
 -19.55530858 -18.95608912 -19.64894855 -21.08583017 -19.67611242
 -16.98516684 -19.52183042 -19.35861489 -19.45113249 -19.46748808
 -19.56511028 -19.01836861 -19.07039287 -18.71520888 -18.5959465
 -19.27673143 -18.46111878 -19.04900086 -19.46237401 -18.85288474
 -18.94376487 -19.56129631 -18.25373565 -19.0402584  -19.11021341
 -20.14313411 -19.0094892  -19.85736922 -19.32347224 -17.54212938
 -18.20511008 -19.15334887 -19.4630462  -19.10668158 -19.12292187
 -19.49888379 -18.98698548 -19.63296244 -17.43109707 -19.27344865
 -19.72353021 -19.50492931 -19.01556334 -17.99341048 -19.82498055
 -19.3700599  -18.9952582  -19.33534228 -19.06240718 -20.24151987
 -18.6909794  -19.47474624 -19.376      -19.66818612 -18.48562058
 -19.1816036  -18.73009615 -19.3802243  -19.65062917 -19.51094855
 -19.27075625 -19.2643377  -19.50928051 -18.71288474 -19.00752556
 -19.40530082 -18.66894989 -18.95206887 -19.11472505 -19.12601863
 -19.69488474 -19.18050614 -19.51813053 -18.66365612 -19.06866347
 -19.44236792 -19.3181134  -19.34606887 -19.69606887 -17.68377874
 -19.48058667 -19.26539543 -19.59919024 -17.13415424 -18.22039643
 -19.44696389 -18.81278115 -19.15695593 -19.25948629 -18.95651017
 -17.82323224 -19.25454228 -18.90437568 -19.00375282 -19.33312158
 -18.23805935 -16.13066692 -19.24173249 -18.43009615 -18.68278974
 -18.76883915 -18.91382004 -18.91016051 -18.87812918 -18.97871676
 -18.38917104 -18.87380696 -18.91447676 -19.36974539 -18.40749787
 -18.7171065  -19.17753134 -18.6437204  -17.75627028 -19.22785715
 -18.942218   -18.83139643 -18.57414917 -17.74068247 -17.39696523
 -17.54715024 -18.94085716 -18.80297694 -17.4693065  -18.69845481
 -19.24505873 -18.18606275 -18.41842275 -18.72615948 -19.24477489
 -18.24605686 -19.12704995 -18.55301631 -19.02873324 -18.20360428
 -19.01807643 -18.8576467  -16.72642346 -18.73290347 -19.57792461
 -18.46440018 -16.75837926 -19.01840605 -18.84268086 -19.16249228
 -19.1452556  -18.85670293 -16.61269149 -19.32322472 -19.61336086
 -19.14713205 -19.00167389 -19.21950828 -18.57434855 -18.89538237
 -19.1956379  -19.27185286 -18.26925481 -19.14838955 -17.24333935
 -19.07210494 -18.59402238 -19.11365325 -19.15965481 -19.40565246
 -19.29119889 -19.36227222 -18.88348    -19.00418308 -18.83466448
 -18.70841888 -18.71623118 -18.78792767 -17.58485304 -18.76253556
 -19.46880445 -19.68363138 -16.65476254 -18.91970674 -18.16549078
 -18.94279389 -18.80437489 -18.06376891 -18.44935273 -19.27794347
 -18.25822884 -19.06764426 -19.4229065  -17.69461134 -18.4704577
 -18.7862643  -19.64512929 -19.49212929 -19.71412929 -18.56740838
 -19.11224461 -19.07288479 -17.9825899  -19.04773481 -19.56360284
 -17.9825899  -20.85540746 -16.72785864 -18.28513249 -19.33713249
 -22.87091889 -21.13739543 -23.27644629 -19.58028995 -20.57171676
 -19.11361694 -21.49140009  -8.49565849 -18.84206887 -18.96128036
 -18.99272505 -18.78201863 -18.86486674 -19.85488474 -18.71650614
 -19.42013053 -18.54165612 -18.82666347 -19.20436792 -19.1821134
 -19.53206887 -18.37421924]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error was in parameter s=2 (number of knots) - it's very small for your data. 
It works with s=237 for example, but not with 236.
As i understand it must be greater or equal than number of observations plus degree of the smoothing spline.

Comment: `s` [is *not* the number of knots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906126/spline-representation-with-scipy-interpolate-poor-interpolation-for-low-amplitu/8944934#8944934), as [explained in the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html).